# Как посмотреть предыдущие распродажи (промоакции) в Google Play Console и создать новую распродажу (промоакцию)?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Как посмотреть **предыдущие распродажи** (промоакции) в Google Play Console и **создать новую распродажу** (промоакцию)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Войдите в **Google Play Console**

**Посмотреть распродажи:**

- 1. **Выберите приложение**
- 2. **Выберите Настройки страницы приложения**
- 3. **Выберите Продажа платного приложения**

Откроется Список распродаж данного приложения. Там же будет кнопка для создания Новой распродажи.

**Посмотреть промоакции:**

- 1. **Выберите приложение**
- 2. **Выберите Источники трафика**
- 3. **Выберите Промоакции**

Откроется Список промоакций данного приложения. Там же будет кнопка для создания Новой промоакции.

**Рис**. к **Посмотреть промоакции:**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вы умудряетесь в течении пары секунд и задать вопрос и дать на него ответ? Для чего?

Comment: Я делюсь своим опытом!!! Я искал решение, нашел его и поделился им! ) Только тем делюсь, что потребовалось в моей текущей практике! Т.е. не теорией, а решением возникшего "жизненного" (реального) вопроса. (Если его нет, конечно, в базе вопросов). Т.е. способствую наполнению Базы практических вопросов.